# Cleaning spreadsheet using regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to remove all but the statistic in every entry of the following:

```
#ChangeColumnFullTimeGraduatesEmployedAtGraduation:74.3%    #ChangeColumnAverageStartingSalaryAndBonus:$134,360 3.4 #ChangeColumnFullTimeGraduatesEmployedThreeMonthsAfterGraduation:81.4%  #ChangeColumnPeerAssessmentScoreOutOf5.:4.3
#ChangeColumnFullTimeGraduatesEmployedAtGraduation:82.0%    #ChangeColumnAverageStartingSalaryAndBonus:$127,368 3.29    #ChangeColumnFullTimeGraduatesEmployedThreeMonthsAfterGraduation:89.8%  #ChangeColumnPeerAssessmentScoreOutOf5.:4.1
#ChangeColumnFullTimeGraduatesEmployedAtGraduation:80.7%    #ChangeColumnAverageStartingSalaryAndBonus:$123,177 3.4 #ChangeColumnFullTimeGraduatesEmployedThreeMonthsAfterGraduation:92.5%  #ChangeColumnPeerAssessmentScoreOutOf5.:4.0
```

I've been trying to use regular expressions (regex).  Based on the fact that the desired final output consists of no more than a number an a percent sign / $ sign, this is what I cobbled together:

```
import re
import csv

with(open('sheet.csv','rU')) as f:

    for row in f:
        re.sub([^0-9\$\%],'',row)
```

which returns this syntax error:

```
re.sub([^0-9\$\%],'',row)
```

Comment: Note that when it reports a syntax error, the line below has a `^` that points to the spot on that line where the error occured.  It is most helpful if you include that as well so we can see where the syntax error is occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regexes are parsed from strings, use a string as argument to re.sub, i.e.

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^0-9\$\%]','',row)
```

or maybe you want to split instead:

```
>>> [c for c in re.split(r'[^0-9\$\%\.]',row) if c]
['74.3%', '$134', '360', '3.4', '81.4%', '5.', '4.3']
```

It is actually still not correct, as you have numbers in your column labels. If your input looks exactly like your example, something like this might work better:

```
re.split(r'#[^:]+:|[ ,]',row)
'74.3%', '$134', '360', '3.4', '81.4%', '4.3'
```

Comment: Note that the OP's regex is not actually correct, unless he doesn't mind deleting all the decimal points.

Comment: Yes, I noted and silently added that :) Thanks for clarifying though. And it is still not correct, as numbers are part of the cell texts as well.